# Example of tying data to the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js

I read the following in [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/#examples)' page:

> When working on a web application that involves a lot of JavaScript,
>   one of the first things you learn is to stop tying your data to the
>   DOM. It's all too easy to create JavaScript applications that end up
>   as tangled piles of jQuery selectors and callbacks, all trying
>   frantically to keep data in sync between the HTML UI, your JavaScript
>   logic, and the database on your server. For rich client-side
>   applications, a more structured approach is often helpful.

I'm not sure if I quite understand the passage above (I'm not sure if I quite understand the need to use Backbone.js either).

Can anyone give me an example of tying data to the DOM and how Backbone.js solves it?

**EDIT:**

Is this an example of it?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Header
  jQuery('#header #searchbox').attr('placeholder', '<?php echo pll__("Header Search Field"); ?>');

(etc...)
```

(Its a hack I used since I didn't know how to do it with php).

So if I modify the ID of `#searchbox` or move its position, the code won't work again. Is that what the passage above refers to?

Comment: Have you had a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715295/backbone-js-and-jquery/#9723401

Comment: A better example might be if you're displaying someone's avatar in multiple places on a single page. What happens someone changes their avatar? With Backbone (or similar tool), everyone gets `'change'` events and redraws themselves, without Backbone you're stuck making sure everyone gets updated by hand; doing it by hand tends to lead to a big pile of interconnected confusion and frustration. The fundamental use case behind this example is having the same information displayed in several (possibly varying in number) places at once.

Answer (score 1):

I've just done something using backbone that displays a modal edit box, where you can edit the name of a project. As this name is also displayed on the main page I want to update that at the same time. But I don't want to identify the DOM element and update it directly with the result of my edit.
Instead I create a backbone model:

```
this.newModel = new app.Project({model: this.model});
```

I then listen to the new Model for any changes, in this case for the project_name attribute:

```
this.listenTo(this.newModel, 'change:project_name', this.updateName);
```

I then create a new view using the 'newModel'

```
modal = new app.ProjectModal({
            model: this.newModel,
        });
```

This is then displayed and if the name changes in the modal view, the 'this.updateName' function is triggered in the 'parent' view, therefore removing any need to identify where the actual DOM element is.

The whole 'parent' function looks like this:

```
    app.ProjectCardView = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName: 'article',
        className: 'project',

        template: _.template( $("#tpl-project-card-summary").html() ),

        events: {
            'click .settings-btn': 'showProjectModal'
        },

        initialize: function() {

            //a slightly different model is used to populate project than this card...
            this.newModel = new app.Project({model: this.model});
            return this;
        },

        render: function() {

            this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
            return this;
        },

        showProjectModal: function (e) {

            this.listenTo(this.newModel, 'change:project_name', this.updateName);

                this.modal = new app.ProjectModal({
                    model: this.newModel
                });
                return this;

        },

        updateName: function() {

            if (this.modal) {
                this.$el.find('.item_name').text(this.model.get("project_name"));
            }

            return this;
        }

    });
```

Obviously I have to update the DOM somewhere, but now it is decoupled from the edit and easier to manage.