# Is Backbone.js is alternative for jQuery and Exactly when to go for backbone.js?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

Now we are using jQuery in our project.Now i want to change some of the code from jQuery to `Backbone`.But when i searched on the google i found some tutorial . I understand from that we can not use Backbone alone.We need to use this with `jQuery` or `MoolTools`.

Am i correct or not?I am really get confused with this. Actually i thought that i can use Backbone.js as alternative to the jQuery.

Please help me some information on that.When to go for Backbone?Thanks in advance....

Comment: why downvote.Please give me the reason then only i can correct my problem

Answer (score 2):

> Backbone is typically used for single page applications. So
>   while jQuery is a toolbox that can be used with any webpage, Backbone
>   is meant for a specific type of application and helps you organize
>   your code for it. At least in my experience one of the biggest
>   challenges in building a single page app is keeping the code clean and
>   modular, and backbone helps a great deal with this.

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715295/backbone-js-and-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You use jQuery (or Zepto etc) in conjunction with Backbone. Backbone is used to bring structure to your javascript application. When used in with a modular library like Require.js, it forces you to write scalable and testable applications with ease. I am not sure if you have written a javascript-heavy application or website, but if you have, you will understand the inherent difficulties.

I honestly find Backbone makes me a better javascript programmer. I can write small modular functions that are easier to test and scale. I can say with confidence, that I would use it for any javascript heavy application or website just because of it's unopinionated nature. I like to describe it as a library of best practices.